# How to make a dynamic Firebase variable and not have it hardcoded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios, use-effect

so I basically have a variable 'balance' with value 5000 in Firebase.

```
{
  "balance" : 5000
}
```

I am using axios and UseEffect hook to fetch the data

```
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('***************.firebasedatabase.app/balance.json')
            .then(res => setBalance(res.data));
  })
```

All I want is when I click this button:

```
<button onClick={() => setBalance(balance - 10)}>Decrease</button>
```

The balance to decrease in the FireBase database and to be visualised in this paragraph:

```
<p>{balance}</p>
```

but instead it just stays hardcoded at 5000 and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing many mistakes

1. Add balance in the state

```
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(5000);
```

2. assuming in `res.data` you are getting 2000
3. Your button state-changing syntax is wrong

```
<button onClick={() => setBalance(prev => prev - 10)}>Decrease</button>
```

4. Now you will get a value of `1990` if you press the button

Comment: It still seems to be hardcoding it for some reason.

Comment: so please create a snippet or demo of your problem in code sandbox, so we know where you do mistake

Comment: I literally have the problem I described and tried the things you said, but they still seem to be hardcoded, when I try to click the button, for a split second I see 1990 and then it resets to 2000

Comment: Its something called after button click, like useEffect or any listeners?